# Sketch effect on an image in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmap

I am working on an image editor app having functions like cropping, text rendering, framing etc. I want to implement sketch effect now ie, the photo shall be converted to sketch. I am using Nokia.Graphics.Imaging.Managed library for doing it. It works very fine but only in wp8. 
the dll is not compatible for wp7. Please suggest me any free library or any image manipulation method to achieve the functionality.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Aviary](http://www.aviary.com/wp7) I've used in the past. Read their terms and conditions if you decide to go with their SDK.